# how to render the side panel from left side?

Tags: angular

I have  sidenav component which is being toggled from a button.
But upon being toggled it is opening from top,but i want it to open from left side.
How can I implement it?
My navigation component:

```html
<div>
    <mat-toolbar>  
        <button (click)="toggleSidenav()">
            Course Details
        </button>
    </mat-toolbar>

    <mat-sidenav-container *ngIf="open">
        <mat-sidenav></mat-sidenav>
        <mat-sidenav-content>
            <mat-list>
                <mat-list-item>Accounts</mat-list-item>
                <mat-list-item>UserProfile</mat-list-item>
                <mat-list-item>Contact me</mat-list-item>
                <mat-list-item>Gspeed</mat-list-item>   
            </mat-list>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `mode` property in your `mat-sidenav` component.

```html
<mat-sidenav mode="side">
```

And all things considered, I guess you are misusing the `sidenav` component. According to [the doc](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview), you should put your list of links inside the `mat-sidenav` component. The content of `mat-sidenav-content` is instead the real content of your page. For example, your `app.component.html` could look like :

```html
<mat-sidenav-container>

    <mat-sidenav>
        <mat-nav-list>
        ...
        </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav-content>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: i did like  this 
  <mat-toolbar>  <button (click)="toggleSidenav()">
          Course Details
      </button>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <div>
 <mat-sidenav-container *ngIf="open" >
  <mat-sidenav mode="side">
      <mat-list>  <mat-list-item> Pepper </mat-list-item>
        <mat-list-item> Salt </mat-list-item>
               </mat-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
        <mat-sidenav-content>
        hello
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
</div> in  my navigation.component.html.I am not able to see<mat-side-nav> patt.Hello part is being rendered.

Comment: Also I am importing it main app.component.html like this<div class="content">
    <app-navigation ></app-navigation>
  </div>

Comment: There is an example on [the official doc](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples) that does exactly what you need. The example is called **Sidenav open & close behavior**. You should check it out and see what's different with your code.